# INSERT multiple rows from SELECT in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

As described in the PostgreSQL [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html) one can add multiple rows in a single `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
    ('6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    ('6120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy');
```

Also a nested `SELECT` query like this works:

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind)
     SELECT table.code, 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'
     FROM other_table AS table2;
```

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to do both at the same time:

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) 
SELECT
    (table.code + 100, 'abc', NULL, t2.date_prod, t2.kind),
    (table.code + 200, 'xyz', NULL, t2.date_prod, t2.kind)
FROM other_table AS t2;
```

If `other_table` contained only `(61717 | 'Tampopo' | NULL | '1985-02-10' | 'Comedy')`, the result table would look like this:

```
 code | title |  did |   date_prod  |   kind
--------------------------------------------------
61817 | 'abc' | NULL | '1985-02-10' | 'Comedy'
61917 | 'xyz' | NULL | '1985-02-10' | 'Comedy'
```

[This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4884e/3/0) should explain it further...

Could you please point me to where I am going wrong. If possible, I would like to avoid multiple lookups in `other_table AS t2` because it is a `VIEW` and it takes considerable time to construct.

Comment: `table.code + 100` is also not going to work. `code` seems to be a character column, you can't  use `+` with strings. Plus: what is the expected result of `'HG120' + 100` - that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Uff. Sorry. Tried to make things clearer... It should have been an `INT`.

Answer (score 14):

Generally you can use `select` with `union`:

```
insert into films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) 
    select t2.code + 100, t2.title, NULL::float, t2.date_prod, t2.kind
    from other_table AS t2
union
    select t2.code + 200, t2.title, NULL::float, t2.date_prod, t2.kind
    from other_table AS t2;
```

In the particular case you described, you can use the `unnest (array [])`:

```
insert into films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) 
    select 
        unnest(array[t2.code + 100, t2.code + 200]), 
        t2.title, NULL::float, t2.date_prod, t2.kind
    from other_table AS t2
```

Comment: The same problem applies to your solution :( Try uncommenting: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4884e/3/0

Comment: Simple cast. See the edited answer. (You should give the table definition earlier in the question).

Comment: Ok last time I bother - promised :) Your second solution is interesting because with `UNION` it seems that the `other_table` VIEW is constructed twice, which is quite expensive in my case. Could the array be extended to the other values or the entire row?

Comment: There is no general rule, but the use of `unnest(array[])` for several columns is a bit more complicated. However, you can always check what the result the `select` gives before using it in the `insert`. Or ask a new question ;)

Comment: @n1000
You could use the `WITH` statement in order to extract a common table from the query,
So the query will start like `WITH other_table AS (....)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `INSERT INTO ... UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind)
SELECT t2.code + 100, t2.title, t2.did, t2.date_prod, t2.kind
FROM other_table AS t2
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.code + 200, t2.title, t2.did, t2.date_prod, t2.kind
FROM other_table AS t2;
```

Comment: @n1000 Updated, anyway the UNION ALL will do the job

Comment: will this cause the VIEW other_table to be constructed twice?

Comment: Probably not, but to be sure check execution plan

Comment: @n1000 Could you decide on one version?  Now the title is hardcoded value `abc` and `xyx` or how it depends on table2?

Comment: :) There was another answer that assumed I wanted to do a loop and suggested `+rownumber() * 100`. So I felt like I should make that clearer...

Comment: @n1000 Just let me know. Does my solution do the job or not?

Comment: Weird, I get `Exception: column "did" is of type double precision but expression is of type text` when there is a `NULL`

Comment: @n1000 share film and other_table defintions

Comment: Since you're just inserting `NULL` into `did` you can exclude it from the `insert` and `select`:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eeee1/1/0

Answer (score -1):

use construction

```
insert into table(column1)
((select uuid from table2))
```